# IntelliJ IDEA scripting

Tags: java, scripting, intellij-idea, structural-search

Is there some console app (may be pluging) which would allow me to control IDEA via a script (not via the GUI)?

Example script I want to write:

```
find all classes that ends with "Factory"
Refactor:rename method XXX with XXXNew
put annottion on class @Entity
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this with idea you should use [Structural Search and Replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html)

this enables you to alter classes as described-

SSR is part of the Ultimate Edition only.

Comment: Since IntelliJ IDEA 14 SSR is included in the Community edition also.